# Unexpected output with DumpMem in MASM - Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have written a simple small assembly program in MASM but the output I am getting is unexpected and is prefixed by 3. Like i have entered `12345` on displaying it shows output as

> 31 32 33 34 35

Where as if I don't take input from user and hard code it like `mystring byte 1,2,3,4,6` - It shows output like `01 02 03 04 06`

Help me in understanding this behavior - Thanks in advance

Here is program code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
disp byte "Enter String : ",0
mystring byte 5 dup(?)

.code 
main PROC
mov edx,offset disp
call writestring
mov edx, offset mystring
mov ecx, 50
call ReadString
mov esi, offset mystring
mov ecx, lengthof mystring
mov ebx, TYPE mystring
call dumpmem

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dumping the hexadecimal values of the ASCII codes of the characters in your string, since this is how they are stored in memory. 31 hex = ASCII '0', 32 hex = ASCII '1', etc.

Note that to convert an ASCII digit such as '0' to its corresponding byte value you need to subtract 0x30. Conversely you can convert a decimal digit stored as a byte to its equivalent ASCII character code by adding 0x30.

Comment: Oh my bad - it didn't click me. Thanks :)

Comment: Try entering a non-numeric string like "Hello world", just for fun.

Comment: Yeah i try it. Actually, i am just new to assembly :P

Comment: One more request, since i am new i would love if you give me any Tip for learning assembly, please

Comment: Yes, just find good example source code and study it until you understand how it works. Being able to read and understand asm is a useful skill even when you're working with HLLs.